# Чем можно победить input:-webkit-autofill?

Tags: html, css

Дефолтный стиль хрома не позволяет изменить бэкграунд автоматически заполненного поля. В чем кроется сия загвоздка, может кто знает?

Comment: то что не меняется через css это [Баг][1] и что то не спешат его фиксить.

[1][http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1334]

Comment: они вообще неторопливые на фикс багов, а не некоторые просто забивают

Answer (score 8):

Переопределить у тебя ее не получится, т.к. эта штука вшита. Я использовал такой CSS-хак:

```
.some_input{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #fff;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #000;
}
```

т.е. перекрываем бэкграунд внутренней тенью.

Answer (score 6):

Нужен был прозрачный фон или градиент. Сделал вот так и фон стал прозрачным. Если убрать строку с градиентом - возвращается желтый фон, но если ее оставить, то можно задать любой цвет в строке где transparent у меня.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus
input:-webkit-autofill, 
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 0;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #ссс;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px transparent inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,174,255,0.04) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 51%,rgba(0,174,255,0.03) 100%);  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот работающий метод - во всех современных браузерах (opera, chrome, edge, firefox)
Добавьте такие стили css

```css
@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
  to {
    color: inherit;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Это перекроет цвета которыми браузер заполняет поля ввода

Answer (score 3):

[Пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416597/116546), что лечится так:

```
input:focus {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

function loadPage() // Вызывается на onload
{
    if (document.login)//if the form login exists, focus:
    {
        document.login.name.focus();//the username input
        document.login.pass.focus();//the password input
        document.login.login.focus();//the login button (submitbutton)
    }
}
```

Хотя это пахнет костылями. Но, похоже, переопределить стиль без отключения автозаполнения не получается.

Или отключить автозаполнение (`autocomplete="off"`).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, но я искал css-решение.

Comment: Еще как пахнет. Что если пользователь уже куда-то ткнул и хотел бы, что продолжить работу с интерфейсом без этих фокусов?

Comment: похоже, css-решения не существует. Надеюсь, что ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 3):

Можно выключить для всей формы:

```
<form autocomplete="off"></form>
```

или для конкретного поля:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Это сработает, но автозаполнение перестанет работать полностью.

Другим вариантом является задание большой внутренней тени для полей с цветом равным цвету желаемого фона:

```
input {outline: none;}
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #fff !important; /* Цвет фона */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не плохой костыль :)

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: Или полный контроль через анимацию

`@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
    to {
        color: #666;
        background: transparent;
    }
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}`

Answer (score -4):

```
<input ... autofocus />
```

У меня работает

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?