# Google Chrome: после очистки input'ы продолжают сохранять признак полей, где значения были выбраны, а не введены

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-chrome

Ситуация такая. Есть форма, на ней есть несколько полей, значения которых пользователь может выбрать из ранее введенных. Типичная ситуация, все браузеры такое позволяют. Однако, в Google Chrome происходит странная ситуация: после того, как форма обрабатывается скриптом и поля очищаются, у них все равно остается признак полей, которые были ранее заполнены каким-то выбранным, а не введенным значением, проще говоря - сохраняют желтый фон. Ниже поясняющая раскадровка.

Только зашли на страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заполнили поля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отправили:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как это исправить?`

Comment: Вы не код очищаюй поля приведите, а весь код этой странички. HTML, css, js.

Comment: пробуйте менять еще стили webkit,
смотрите тут http://usabili.ru/news/2010/01/13/input-in-chrome.html?comment_added=1  и тут https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543
и наверное после удаления значения нужно еще переопределить стили

Comment: @Oleksandr, отлично, только не совсем понятно, как с помощью jquery такое реализовать, в смысле как отобрать элемент по такому селектору. Я по всякому попробовал - не выходит. Может вынесете ваш комментарий в ответ и попробуете там написать код? Там и обсудить можно будет.

Comment: @Moonvvell, самый обычный код, строка из js приведена в посте, код html формы сейчас добавлю в вопрос

Comment: @Moonvvell впрочем, `placeholder` отпустило и он заработал как надо. Но с цветом все равно беда, и в html-коде там ничего необычного нет.

Comment: Поскольку это стандартное поведение браузера (Хрома в данном случае), то подумайте дважды перед тем, как его убирать. Если вдруг человек привык к тому, что автозаполненные поля формы выглядят таким образом, то может и не надо это переопределять?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, это совершенно не стандартное поведение браузера, так как стандартно после очищения полей они становится обратно с тем фоном, с каким и были. Ровно то же хочу сделать и я - после того, как поля очистились, они должны стать как прежде

Comment: Думаю стоит после отправки формы таки выставить аттрибут `autocomplete="off"`, хотя бы до фокуса.

Comment: @vp_arth а вот это уже интереснее, согласен. Если не найдется вариант с установкой через css параметра `important`, так и поступлю. Может вынесете свой комментарий в ответ?

Comment: почему-то сразу сассоциировал `поля очищаются`, как `.reset()`

Comment: Дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/94389

Comment: @Vadizar хм, но там же нет ответа и условие не то, мне нужно динамическое

Answer (score 7, accepted):

После отправки формы нужно ее сбросить методом `.reset()`, тогда желтый фон уберется.

```js
document.querySelector('b').onclick = function() {
  
  // ваш код по обработке формы
  
  document.querySelector('form').reset();
}
```

```css
b {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form name="ololo">
  <input type=text name=name>
  <input type=text name=phone>
  <input type=text name=address>
  <b>submit</b>
</form>
```

Comment: О! То, что нужно.

Comment: Тогда не стесняйтесь принимать ответ )

Comment: да-да, я просто свою телегу сначала дописал ) Спасибо!

Comment: Изобретаете велосипед.

Comment: А вы как всегда умеете аргументировать.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko это бредовое решение, когда есть вариант на чистом CSS. В чем проблема адаптировать стили под дизайн и использовать решение на CSS? Зачем писать костыли на JS?

Comment: вы всегда можете предоставить свой, невелосипедный вариант. пока что ваш вариант полностью переопределяет дефолтное поведение браузера, что как раз и есть велосипед.

Comment: Присоединюсь к @SashaOmelchenko - мне нужен был наиболее нативный вариант сбросить форму, стили меня абсолютно устраивают хромовские

Answer (score 4):

Оставлю ответ и сам. На мой взгляд, это лучше вынести из комментариев, так как информация важная. В результате общения выяснилось, что по сути нам нужно перебить значение, которое выставляет сам Chrome, а именно:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189);}
```

В случае, если это был бы обычный css, мы бы просто сделали примерно так (взял у пользователя из другого ответа):

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px #fff !important; /* Цвет фона */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #999 !important; /* цвет текста */
    color: #999 !important; /* цвет текста */
}
```

Но задача стояла сделать это динамически. При этом по умолчанию `.css()` [не работает](http://api.jquery.com/css/) с `important`:

> Note: .css() ignores !important declarations. So, the statement $( "p"
>   ).css( "color", "red !important" ) does not turn the color of all
>   paragraphs in the page to red. It's strongly advised to use classes
>   instead; otherwise use a jQuery plugin.

Выход был найден [тут](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173#comment:5):

```
js:
$('#contact_us').find('input:-webkit-autofill').addClass('importantBackground');

css:
.importantBackground {
    background-color: #BA383D!important;
  }
}
```

Но в итоге ситуация стала явно похожа либо на баг в браузере, либо на попытку разработчиков браузера быть самыми умными. Не смотря на то, что в инспекторе мы видим вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фон все равно оставался желтым. Было испробовано и второе решение, которое предложил другой пользователь — отключить autofill после очистки формы и включать по получению полями фокуса на них.

```
$('#contact_us').find('input, textarea').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Но и оно не помогло:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге ответ [был найден](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628628/218094). Нужно использовать чистый js и на форме вызывать метод `reset()`.

Comment: можете и не на ваниле вызывать:`$(this)[0].reset();` или `$(this).trigger( 'reset' )`

Comment: Изобретаете велосипед.

Comment: @Vadizar ну я так, задокументировал что описывали, а вообще верный ответ я уже отметил.

Comment: @Станислав ну это бред, когда есть вариант на CSS. В чем проблема адаптировать стили под ваш дизайн и использовать его?

Comment: @Vadizar жажда познания :)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю стоит после отправки формы таки выставить аттрибут `autocomplete="off"`.

Жёлтым фоном браузер как бы подсказывает пользователю, что у него есть данные для автозаполнения этой формы.

---

[w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute)

> The autocompletion mechanism must be implemented by the user agent
>   acting as if the user had modified the element's value, and must be
>   done at a time where the element is mutable (e.g. just after the
>   element has been inserted into the document, or when the user agent
>   stops parsing).

Другими словами, если при отправке формы страница не обновляется - придётся перегенерить форму заново.

Comment: Если данные отправляются аяксом, то установка этого атрибута после отправки формы и очистки полей не решит проблему.

Comment: Изобретаете велосипед.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, я почему-то сразу подумал, что именно `.reset` не работает, баг типа такой. А заново сгенерированная  форма с отключенным автокомплитом должна сработать.

Comment: @vp_arth да, заново сгерененная абсолютно, но она и так будет какой нужно, без reset() - а про него, если честно, я вообще забыл.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1**

Параметр `autocomplete="off"` на `input`.

**Вариант 2**

```
:-webkit-autofill {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px #fff !important; /* Цвет фона */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #999 !important; /* цвет текста */
    color: #999 !important; /* цвет текста */
}
```

Comment: Абсолютно не решит, зачем я пользователей буду лишать этой возможности, да еще и на таком критичном участке, где нужна конверсия побольше - заставлять их набирать руками данные поля - серьезный урон по бизнесу чьему-то.

Comment: @Станислав тогда наслаждайтесь желтым полем.

Comment: Спасибо, но нет :)

Comment: @Станислав прикрепил второй вариант

Comment: @Vadizar я давал ссылку на этот вариант, но как я понял ему нужно удаление цвети, а не его отключение со старта

Comment: А вы пробовали его?

Comment: @Oleksandr чтобы не писать лишние комментарии.

Comment: @Oleksandr да, мне нужно переопределить это свойство. Ситуация в том, что это делалось бы примерно так `$('#contact_us').find('input:-webkit-autofill').css('background-color', '#BA383D');`, если не одно но, в оф документации по .css() написано вот что ==Note: .css() ignores !important declarations. So, the statement $( "p" ).css( "color", "red !important" ) does not turn the color of all paragraphs in the page to red. It's strongly advised to use classes instead; otherwise use a jQuery plugin.==

Comment: Изобретаете велосипед

Comment: @vp_arth как раз таки это нормальное решение.

Comment: Единственное нормальное решение - это `.reset()`. Пользователь, привыкший к автозаполнению(и к жёлтому цвету) вам спасибо не скажет ни за первый, ни за второй вариант