# Как правильно очистить форму во Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mvvm, vue.js

Подобный вопрос [уже был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628567/google-chrome-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-input%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0/628628#628628), про сброс формы через метод `reset()` я знаю. В примерах по работе с Vue.js пишут, что значения полей формы сбрасываются выставлением в модель пустого значения, пример:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#form',
  data: {
    email: '',
    name: '',
    
    submitted: {
      name: '',
      email: ''
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    formSubmit: function(event) {
      this.submitted.name = this.name;
      this.submitted.email = this.email;
      
      this.name = this.email = '';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" @submit.prevent="formSubmit">
  <div class="form__line"><input v-model="name" name="name" type="text" /></div>
  <div class="form__line"><input v-model="email" name="email" type="email" /></div>
  <div class="form__line"><button>Submit</button></div>
  
  <output style="display: block; margin-top: 1em">
    <div>{{ submitted.name }}</div>
    <div>{{ submitted.email }}</div>
  </output>
</form>
```

Однако, если выбирать значение из автокомплита, отправлять форму, а потом просто чистить модель, то форма после этих действий будет выглядеть вот так (Chrome):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как очистить форму без таких побочных эффектов?

Comment: Побочный эффект - это цвет бэкграунда? Его стилями хрома можно поправить. Или попробовать сделать reset() в дополнении к очистке модели.

Comment: Покажите как правильно применить `reset()`, я запихивал его в метод, обращаясь к `event.target`, но там потом связь с моделью терялась. Переопределять стили это не ок )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убрать фон вот так:

```
methods: {
    formSubmit: function(event) {
      this.submitted.name = this.name;
      this.submitted.email = this.email;

      this.name = this.email = '';
      event.target.reset();
    }
  }
```

Но в вашем примере есть какая-то проблема с output тэгом, если убрать внутри `<div>`, то все заработает:

```
<output style="display: block; margin-top: 1em">
  {{ submitted.name }}
  {{ submitted.email }}
</output>
```

Почему это влияет, затрудняюсь ответить..

Comment: Смахивает на необходимость отправлять баг-репорт :-)
В моем прошлом вопросе вы ответили, что взаимодействовать с DOM во ViewModel напрямую неправильно, так вот — через `event.target` мы разве не делаем такое неправильное взаимодействие?

Comment: Трудно сказать чья это проблема) вроде и не браузера, т.к. он имеет право создавать свои стили для автокомплита, но и не vue тоже, т.к. он свою задачу выполнят - поля очищает, а отвечать за то, что браузер применяет доп. стили тоже не его забота.

Comment: Если интересно, то я смог локализовать этот баг — все дело в теге `<output>`, по всей видимости, во время сброса формы Vue сбрасывает его содержимое полностью, теги удаляются, а значит и некуда выводить модель. Если аутпут заменить на див, например, будет норм работать с вложенными тегами.

Comment: Ага, видел эту особенность, когда делал эксперимент. Я почитал спецификацию этого тэга на w3c, он ведь служит только для вывода расчетов скрипта и у ему при ресете формы тоже выставляется дефолтное значение и похоже, что это выставление убивает все тэги внутри него. Но как до конца это работает так и не понял. Почему, например, дивы убиваются не сразу после сабмита (если reset добавить), а только после второго сабмита.