# Добавление псевдоэлемента к input:-webkit-autofill

Tags: html, css

Как добавить псевдоэлемент before/after к input__area только при условии, что input__area будет содержать псевдокласс &:-webkit-autofill? То есть, input__area:-webkit-autofill отображаем before/after, в любом другом случае - не отображаем.

```
<div className="input"}>
    <label className="input__label" htmlFor="email">Email</label>
    <input className="input__area" type="email" name="email" id="email"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Тег input не имеет псевдоэлементов ::before, ::after

Comment: @GGO я понимаю, но если мы обернем "input.input__area" в div и уже ему зададим псеадоэлемент, то он будет отображаться всегда, а не только при &:-webkit-autofill

Comment: правильно, но лучше обернуть в label) Так-вот вопрос зачем вам такое делать?

Comment: @GGO таким способом хотелось отображать иконку(через псевдоэлемент) когда на инпуте висит &:-webkit-autofill

Comment: Будёт хорошо взглянуть сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/94389/, и сюда https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill